# HQL failed sqlexception

Tags: hive, hiveql

When i run

```
Select * from table_a
```

using my hive ide, I receive:

> SQLException pa current sql input files exceed the maximum limit. Please optimize. Maxfile--→100000

I could find nothing when I google this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you table has exploded the maximum number of allowed HDFS file.

Go to hive (or beeline) and run following command, by default the value is `100000`

```
set hive.exec.max.created.files;
```

To fix the issue, you need to go and check your insert Queries and understand why it's creating so many files.

However for time being and you concatenate some of the partition (better to do it for all) using the following command

```
alter table dbname.tblName partition (col_name=value) concatenate;
```